# Print out array value inside forEach with each iteration

Tags: javascript, jszip

I'm using jsZip to save multiple files into a zip and download it. I can't figure out how to output the array name of that iteration out of the urls array.

The urls array each are the file name that should go inside the `var filename = "";`, just can't find a way to print out each of the array names.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;

var urls = [
    "FirstFile.pdf",
    "SecondFile.pdf",
];

urls.forEach(function(url)
{

  //if iteration #1, then echo firstFile.pdf below, 
  //if iteration #2 echo SecondFile.pdf below so it saves the files inside the zip.
  var filename = "output urls array here as name";


  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }
     zip.file('./temp/' + filename, data, {binary:true});
     count++;

     if (count == urls.length)
     {
       zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content)
       {
          $( ".download" ).click(function() {
            saveAs(content, 'FileZip.zip');
          });             
       });
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is stored in the `url` parameter passed to the anonymous function used with `foreach`.

Therefore, to access the filename on any iteration, simply use `url`

```
var filename = url;
```

In fact, you don't really need a second variable called filename, you could simply amend your later line to look like

```
 zip.file('./temp/' + url, data, {binary:true});
```

Comment: I don't see why that would happen. Have you tried to move the concatenation out in to a separate line and displayed the result? `var filename = './temp/' + url; console.log( filename );`

Answer (score 1):

```
 urls.forEach(function(url)
{

  //if iteration #1, then echo firstFile.pdf below, 
  //if iteration #2 echo SecondFile.pdf below so it saves the files inside the zip.
  var filename = url;

});
```